# Mysql query for list of followers

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how I can obtain the list of user followers and his/her status of following to them. For example, I have 10 followers, and I need to know if I am following them or not. It's a feature like on Instagram, when you can observe people and be observed.

I have one table:

```
follower     user_id     reg_dt       followed
   1            2         date          true
```

In above mentioned example user 1 is followed by user 2. If the user will unfollow, the flag will be false, but it will be in DB.

I want to achieve:

```
follower     user_id     reg_dt     followed     logged_user_follower
   1            2         date        true             false
```

It means that user 1 is followed by user 2, but user 1 is not following user 2.

I tried 2 queries:

```
select follower.follower_id as follower, follower.user_id as user_id, follower.followed as followed, follower.reg_dt as reg_dt
from tb_follower follower
where follower.follower_id=1 and follower.followed=1;
```

to get list of followers (of user 1) and:

```
select 1 as logged_user_follower from tb_follower follower
where follower.follower_id=follower.follower_id and follower.followed=1 and follower.user_id = follower.user_id limit 1
```

to get the status logged_user_follower.

I don't know how to merge this to queries, to do one efficient, to get list all the followers of particular user and his/her status of following to them.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Side note:  have you considered just adding a record for user 2 following user 1 instead of using the logged_user_follower column?  so user 1 and user 2 would both have a record in your follower table if they are following each other.

Comment: Yes, I have that record, but I need to fetch all data once, to create somehow a view with this logged_user column, and I am not pretty sure, how to do that for particular user. I don't want to iterate over all users.

Comment: There's no iteration over all users if you're using mysql joins.  It's not a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to get the inverse record:

```
select f1.follower_id as follower, 
       f1.user_id as user_id, 
       f1.followed as followed, 
       f1.reg_dt as reg_dt,
       coalesce(f2.followed, false) as logged_user_follower
from tb_follower f1
left join tb_follower f2 
   on f1.follower_id = f2.user_id and f1.user_id = f2.follower_id
where f1.follower_id = 1 and f1.followed = 1;
```

Comment: It works, but is it possible to get true or false instead of blob as logged_user_follower?

Comment: @m.aibin You mean get `true` or `false` as a string?

Comment: no, it could be 1 or 0, but I get blob in logged_user_follower column as a result

Comment: the type of followed is bit(1)

Comment: ok, I get it, I used this:
select f1.follower_id as follower, 
       f1.user_id as user_id, 
       f1.followed as followed, 
       f1.reg_dt as reg_dt,
       CAST(coalesce(f2.followed, false) AS CHARACTER(1) CHARACTER SET utf8) AS logger_user_followed
from tb_follower f1
left join tb_follower f2 
   on f1.follower_id = f2.user_id and f1.user_id = f2.follower_id
where f1.follower_id = 384 and f1.followed = 1;

Comment: @m.aibin What do you get if you use `coalesce(f2.followed, 0)` or `ifnull(f2.followed, false)` or `ifnull(f2.followed, 0)`?

Comment: @m.aibin Why do you cast something that is a boolean if you want it to remain a boolean?

Comment: I get BLOB value instead of bit 1 or 0. It's just for a better view.